# Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider missing from SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to import an `.accdb` MS Access database into SQL Server 2008 R2, but cannot find the Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider in the provider list for both the import wizard, and the SSIS. Tried both and not there.

I downloaded and installed MS Access Database Engine 2010, and MS Access Engine 2013, but still not there. How to add this so it will show up in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution :

Download 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Download Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: This solution allows you to have the driver in "Connection Manager" but the data import wizard.