# Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Initially i was not able to see the **microsoft office 12.0 access database engine ole db provider** in my SSMS (SQL Sever 2008)

So I have followed the below link from these posts and installed the access database engine

[Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider missing from SQL Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517167/microsoft-office-12-0-access-database-engine-ole-db-provider-missing-from-sql-se)

From My Control Panel/ Add or remove program.

[image]

But Still I am not able to see the **microsoft office 12.0 access database engine ole db provider** in my SSMS (SQL Sever 2008)

My SQL Server Version : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

P.S I have installed the X64 bit OLEDB only.

[image]

Can anybody suggest what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @ Jonathan my image above clearly displays I am using SQL server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The operation could not be completed.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

---

I googled solution for the above error and found the below .exe file needs to be installed,
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Try to install this and import the Excel file

Thanks Ram